# Running multiple Cucumber features in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, watir, cucumber-jvm

I've been working with Cucumber and Watir for the past few months locally to run some regression tests on our application. I have several Cucumber feature files in one repository with one step file and one environment file. Recently I have moved from running this locally to running it on Jenkins along with the cucumber-jvm reports plugin.

I set the build steps up with the following:

```
cucumber --format json all/features/publish.feature > result_publish.json 
cucumber --format json all/features/signin.feature > result_signin.json
cucumber --format json all/features/reports.feature > result_reports.json
```

When there are no failures with the tests all feature files run successfully one after the other. However, if there is a failure with the first test the build will fail and the subsequent tests will not run.

Is there any way I can force all feature files to run even if one of them fails?

Answer (score 0):

Put the features in the same folder and run

```
cucumber --format json all/features/integration -o results.json
```

This will create one single report with all the tests and will run all the features regarding if they fail or not